# Which files are required if I want to deploy extjs7 app generated by npm to tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, extjs7

As title said,the app now is tool large,100+mb,I wonder which files are required if I want to run app in tomcat.Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

in order to reduce your application's weight, first of all, you should remove from your ExtJS package all compontens from unused framework (for example, if you're using ExtJS Classic in your app, you must remove all Modern packages/files).

Simply with that trick, you'll reduce the weight about 50%.

In my experience with ExtJS applications running on Tomcat, assuming you're facing with ExtJS Classic, I suggest you to include following items in your project.

### 1. Base Components

Primary ExtJS files you must include in your application, of corse, will be:

- 'ext-all-debug.js'
- 'ext-all.js'

### 2. Theme components

Include only components for active theme in your application. For example, include components located in `/classic/theme-material`:

- 'theme-material-debug.js'
- 'theme-material.js'

Others theme's components are useless.

### 3. Packages components

Include only used package.
For example, if your're not using D3 componets, avoid to include them.

Hope this could answear your question and be usefull for your needs..
Cheers